# Проблема с отображением таблицы

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nlp

использовал функцию для отображения результатов тематического моделирования в виде таблицы. Изначально функция работала корректно, а сейчас падает в ошибку, не могу понять в чем дело?

```py
def format_topics_sentences(ldamodel=ldamodel, corpus=textCorpus, texts=docCollTexts):
    # Init output
    sent_topics_df = pd.DataFrame()
    # Get main topic in each document
    for i, row in enumerate(ldamodel[textCorpus]):
        row = sorted(row, key=lambda x: (x[1]), reverse=True)
        # Get the Dominant topic, Perc Contribution and Keywords for each document
        for j, (topic_num, prop_topic) in enumerate(row):
            if j == 0:  # => dominant topic
                wp = ldamodel.show_topic(topic_num)
                topic_keywords = ", ".join([word for word, prop in wp])
                sent_topics_df = sent_topics_df.append(pd.Series([int(topic_num), round(prop_topic,4), topic_keywords]), ignore_index=True)
            else:
                break
    sent_topics_df.columns = ['Dominant_Topic', 'Perc_Contribution', 'Topic_Keywords']
    # Add original text to the end of the output
    contents = pd.Series(texts)
    sent_topics_df = pd.concat([sent_topics_df, contents], axis=1)
    return(sent_topics_df)
df_topic_sents_keywords = format_topics_sentences(ldamodel=ldamodel, corpus=textCorpus, texts=docCollTexts)
# Format
df_dominant_topic = df_topic_sents_keywords.reset_index()
df_dominant_topic.columns = ['Document_No', 'Dominant_Topic', 'Topic_Perc_Contrib', 'Keywords', 'Text']
# Show
df_dominant_topic.head(10)
```

ошибка

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-1553ec6521b9> in <cell line: 20>()
     18     sent_topics_df = pd.concat([sent_topics_df, contents], axis=1)
     19     return(sent_topics_df)
---> 20 df_topic_sents_keywords = format_topics_sentences(ldamodel=ldamodel, corpus=textCorpus, texts=docCollTexts)
     21 # Format
     22 df_dominant_topic = df_topic_sents_keywords.reset_index()

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   6291         ):
   6292             return self[name]
-> 6293         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   6294 
   6295     @final

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'
```

при корректной работе функции таблица выглядела следующим образом
[image: таблица]

если использовать первоначальную запись в dataframe то он пишет все в один столбец
[image: первоначальная запись]

а если новую запись использовать, то просто выдает ошибку
[image: новая запись]

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего `Pandas` обновился до версии 2.0, на английском СО [есть ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75956237/8324991), что `DataFrame.append` больше нет и нужно использовать теперь `pd.concat`. Примерно так:

```py
sent_topics_df = pd.concat([
    sent_topics_df, 
    pd.DataFrame(data=[[int(topic_num), round(prop_topic,4), topic_keywords]], columns=sent_topics_df.columns)
], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Попробовал, теперь выпадает следующая ошибка       ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in _finalize_columns_and_data(content, columns, dtype)
    940     except AssertionError as err:
    941         # GH#26429 do not raise user-facing AssertionError
--> 942         raise ValueError(err) from err
    943 
    944     if len(contents) and contents[0].dtype == np.object_:

ValueError: 0 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns

Comment: Ну, распечатайте, что у вас в этот момент находится в `sent_topics_df` и в остальных переменных. А вообще странно.